# Postprocess field data in wtforms

Tags: flask, wtforms

It's posibble to postprocess the sanitized data in a wtforms field?

For example, I have the following Forms:

```
class ComponentesForm(Form):
    descripcion = StringField()
    area = FloatField(validators=(NumberRange(min=0.01), ))

class OtherForm(Form):
    componentes_paredes = FieldList(FormField(ComponentesForm))
```

The 'componentes_paredes' field data is a list containing dicts. I want to procces this data and convert it into a unique dict (I don't have repeated keys). I know that can be done outside of wtforms, but I don't want to do this in the views.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the context well enough, but probably do it in a controller instead?

Comment: @bubak What do you mean with a controller?. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: in flask for example you have (1) view -- the template, (2) model -- the wtforms object with fields and when submitted, the model is send to server -- (3) the controller is the first object to receive the submitted data (model) -- hence MVC (model-view-controller) -- here you can validate the model, change some values, update some business objects etc -- and -- in your case -- do whatever transformation you desire

Comment: Thanks for the aclaration.